# Trait 'Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesCommands' not found error while laravel upgrading to 5.2 from 5.1?

Tags: php, laravel, upgrade, laravel-5

When I am trying to upgrade from laravel 5.1 to 5.2, I am getting following error

```
Trait 'Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesCommands' not found in D:\xampp\htdocs\Invoice\web\bootstrap\cache\compiled.php
```

My controller class is,

```
    namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesCommands;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;

abstract class Controller extends BaseController {

    use DispatchesCommands,
        ValidatesRequests;

    function __construct() {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }
```

}

In laravel documentation, they saying it [deprecated](https://laravel.com/docs/master/upgrade)

So how can I fix this?

Comment: Little gotchas like this are exactly why I built [Laravel Shift - the automated way to upgrade Laravel](https://laravelshift.com).

Answer (score 17):

Deprecated doesn't mean that it's been removed, just that it will be at some point. They do mention a fix for it in the documentation:

> The `Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesCommands` trait has been deprecated and renamed to `Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs`.

So just replace this:

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesCommands;
```

With this:

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs;
```

There should not be any worries about this breaking in the future as the [`DispatchesCommands`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.1/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bus/DispatchesCommands.php) trait was including the `DispatchesJobs` trait which was also present in another form in 5.1.